# Getting header and footer externally using JSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

We have a SharePoint 2013 site and another associated asp.net website. We would like to build the header(including top nav) and footer of the website so that it matches the header and footer of the SharePoint site.

The top nav is managed through the term store. We were planning to get those elements through JSOM but is it possible to get the whole header and footer through this method?

We would like to avoid having to manage a separate master page that mimics the SharePoint header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

If top or global navigation is getting populated through managed metadata navigation then use Taxonomy.JS to get term groups and term sets..

Here's an article on how to access taxonomy through JS

[Accessing Taxonomy Term Store with JSOM](http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/accessing-taxonomy-term-store-with-jsom/)

Comment: Thanks. This article is for using JSOM within SharePoint. I'm trying to use it outside of SharePoint. Where would I get the SharePoint assembly to include in my project?